# how to reset the password if user forgot the password in firebase and flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, reset-password

I want to reset the forgot password inside app using flutter. I have email verification screen then I use to get an otp that verifies the email after email verification I want to move to new password screen which takes new password as input and resets the password.

How to achive this using firebase flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Check this. you will get password reset email to the email address that is sent to firebase

firebase_exceptions.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

enum AuthStatus {
  successful,
  wrongPassword,
  emailAlreadyExists,
  invalidEmail,
  weakPassword,
  unknown,
}

class AuthExceptionHandler {
  static handleAuthException(FirebaseAuthException e) {
    AuthStatus status;
    switch (e.code) {
      case "invalid-email":
        status = AuthStatus.invalidEmail;
        break;
      case "wrong-password":
        status = AuthStatus.wrongPassword;
        break;
      case "weak-password":
        status = AuthStatus.weakPassword;
        break;
      case "email-already-in-use":
        status = AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists;
        break;
      default:
        status = AuthStatus.unknown;
    }
    return status;
  }

  static String generateErrorMessage(error) {
    String errorMessage;
    switch (error) {
      case AuthStatus.invalidEmail:
        errorMessage = "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.weakPassword:
        errorMessage = "Your password should be at least 6 characters.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.wrongPassword:
        errorMessage = "Your email or password is wrong.";
        break;
      case AuthStatus.emailAlreadyExists:
        errorMessage =
            "The email address is already in use by another account.";
        break;
      default:
        errorMessage = "An error occured. Please try again later.";
    }
    return errorMessage;
  }
}
```

reset_password.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:school/screens/firebase_exception.dart';

class ResetPasswordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'reset_password';
  const ResetPasswordScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResetPasswordScreen> createState() => _ResetPasswordScreenState();
}

class _ResetPasswordScreenState extends State<ResetPasswordScreen> {
  final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  static final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static late AuthStatus _status;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<AuthStatus> resetPassword({required String email}) async {
    await auth
        .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email)
        .then((value) => _status = AuthStatus.successful)
        .catchError(
            (e) => _status = AuthExceptionHandler.handleAuthException(e));

    return _status;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 50.0, bottom: 25.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _key,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.close),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 70),
                const Text(
                  "Forgot Password",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 35,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text(
                  'Please enter your email address to recover your password.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                const Text(
                  'Email address',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    obscureText: false,
                    controller: _emailController,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Empty email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    autofocus: false,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: kDarkGrey),
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: kBlackText,
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(
                            30.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: kSecondaryColor, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(
                            30.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      isDense: true,
                      // fillColor: kPrimaryColor,
                      filled: true,
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      hintText: 'email address',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: kLightWhiteGray),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 2,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: kSecondaryColor,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_key.currentState!.validate()) {
                          final _status = await resetPassword(
                              email: _emailController.text.trim());
                          if (_status == AuthStatus.successful) {
                            //your logic
                          } else {
                            //your logic or show snackBar with error message

                          }
                        }
                      },
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      child: const Text(
                        'RECOVER PASSWORD',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: kBlackText,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't sound like resetting a password, but rather just setting their password. If that's indeed the case, have a look at the documentation on [setting the password for the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#set_a_users_password).

If you really want to reset the user's password, have a look at the documentation on [sending a password reset email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email). Note that there are very few options to customize this flow though

Comment: I figured out that there is no simple way to reset password inside app. So, I am using sendresetemail to reset users password

Answer (score 0):

Just make a simple method and call it like this.

```
    Future forgotPassword({required String email}) async {
      try {
             await _firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
             throw Exception(err.message.toString());
          } catch (err) {
             throw Exception(err.toString());
          }
      }
```